# Какие ограничения в netcore?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .netcore2.0

Изучаю netcore и не ясен вот такой вопрос, в чем разница между .net и netcore, основное отличие в кроссплатформенности netcore и возможностью запускаться на линуксе. Вопрос, .net включает в себя много  различных библиотек и прочего, все это позволяет делать все что хочешь, если я перехожу на netcore, появляются ли какие то ограничения в использовании классов или чего то, что есть в .net или все что есть .net  я могу использовать в netcore? Или должны быть аналоги технологий из .net  в netcore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core не позволяет создавать типы проектов, заточенные под Windows, такие как Windows Forms и WPF. В нем недоступны домены приложений и Remoting, а также некоторые методы классов стандартной библиотеки либо бросают исключения, либо не имеют эффекта на определенных платформах. Подробнее:

[Перенос в .NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/libraries)

[List of behavioral changes/compat breaks and deprecated/legacy APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/ApiCompat)

Answer (score 3):

Это скорее к ответу выше про десктоп. У .NET Core на самом деле появится поддержка WPF и WinForms с версией 3. Правда только на Windows и это скорее всего связано с постепенным уходом MS от модели распространения полного фреймворка. [ссылка](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/)